# How to fix "Reference to non-static member function must be called" in this case?

Tags: c++, sqlite, static

I want to execute sqlite query with specified callback. The only one solution which I can imagine is to define sqliteCallback as a static function but I don't need it static because I want to access there to non-static members of my class. How to properly do it?

```
class SqlDB {

    private:

        int someIntVar;

        int sqliteCallback( void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName ) {
            // Here I should have an access to non-static member: someIntVar
            return 0;
        }

        void query( std::string queryStr ) {

            // Reference to non-static member function must be called:
            int res = sqlite3_exec( _sqlHandle, queryStr.c_str(), SqlDB::sqliteCallback, 0, &_sqlliteErrMsg );

        }

};
```

Comment: Why are they static in the first place then? In any case, you can always pass a reference to an instance to a static function.

Comment: Don't use sqlite3_exec. Use prepare, step and finalize.

Comment: In a `static` version, Your `void *NotUsed` could be `void * instance` which you cast back to a `SqlDB` and use to invoke a member function that does the real work.

Comment: @manni66, why? :)

Comment: You need no C callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sqlite3_exec` allows you to provide a user argument that will be provided along with the callback for whatever purposes you chose. Often this is identification information. Here we will use it to identify the `SqlDB` instance that requested information from the database by providing `this`.

```
void query( std::string queryStr ) {
    int res = sqlite3_exec( _sqlHandle, 
                            queryStr.c_str(), 
                            SqlDB::sqliteCallbackStatic, // use static callback function
                            this, // provide instance
                            &_sqlliteErrMsg );

}

static int sqliteCallbackStatic( void *instance, 
                                 int argc, 
                                 char **argv, 
                                 char **azColName ) {
    SqlDB * db = static_cast<SqlDB *>(instance); // cast instance back to SqlDB
    db->sqliteCallbackMember(argc, argv, azColName); // call member function
    return 0;
}

int sqliteCallbackMember( int argc, char **argv, char **azColName ) {
    // use someIntVar
    return 0;
}
```